# Why I get "sealed resource is missing or invalid file" so often

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, code-signing, xamarin-studio

Xamarin iOS app throws the following error once in 6 or 8 times for no reason.

> tool exited with code a sealed resource is missing or invalid file

I am using the same code signing identity and provisioning profile.

If I face this problem , I have to do a *clean all* and *rebuild* it.

It takes lot of time

Comment: Bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52165

Comment: You mean to say its a known bug

Comment: Yes... you can also come across this "issue" with Apple's code signing tool if you are building to a samba hosted file system if it is misconfigured and creating/deleting hidden .smbdelete files within your app bundle.